# Получение http запроса программой на c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть приложение, которое может отправлять http запросы (а может и https, большая ли разница в данном случае?), и есть приложение на c# windows forms. Можно ли как-то отправлять http запросы с данными, чтобы прога на c# принимала их. Ну и могла эти данные сохранять?

Comment: вам нужен http-сервер (сервис), а не клиентское приложение, для обработки http(s)-запросов

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста точнее, какое поведение программы вы хотите увидеть, если предпринимали самостоятельно какие-то шаги для решения вопроса - укажите их. Из вашего сообщения не совсем понятно, что вам требуется, просто отправлять и получать http/https запросы через программу на C#?

Comment: Создайте проект ASP.NET Core Web API. Гайдов полно, он и будет сервером, принимающим запросы по HTTP например в формате JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Если не использовать тонкости, то между http и https вы не заметите разницы.

Пример кода, который вам может помочь:

```
string url = "https://localhost:7110/GetInfo";
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        string response;
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
            return new { result.id, result.name};
        }
```

Также инфорамацию можно найти
[тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/net/2.2.php).

Comment: Специально привёл разные примеры, потому что по вашему вопросу не очень понятно, что именно вам нужно.

Comment: `Можно ли как-то отправлять http запросы с данными, чтобы прога на c# принимала их`, автору надо, чтобы win forms прога принимала запросы